# How to fix Bundler install EIO error @ io_fread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv, ioerror

I've been having some issues with using bundle install. I'm using Ruby with Rbenv. I've tried creating an empty directory (except for a gemfile, with one listed gem) and setting its permissions to allow anyone to create and modify files and folders, but it still isn't working. Rails installs work, until it gets to the point of running Bundler.

Some people on previous questions have recommended using sudo bundler install (while noting that it isn't a permanent fix) but I get command not found, and I'm wary of installing gems using sudo. There are permission fixes available for RVM, but as I'm using rbenv, these aren't too helpful.

I'm really stuck here. I've tried with both Ruby 2.3.0 and 2.3.1.

Here's my error output:

```
Error details

    Errno::EIO: Input/output error @ io_fread - /home/my_username/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/info/rspec-mocks
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:77:in `read'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:77:in `checksum_for_file'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:70:in `update_info'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:43:in `block in dependencies'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:88:in `block (3 levels) in compact_index_client'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:65:in `apply_func'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:60:in `block in process_queue'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `loop'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `process_queue'
      /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'

Environment

  Bundler   1.12.5
  Rubygems  2.5.1
  Ruby      2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
  GEM_HOME  /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  GEM_PATH  /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0:/home/my_username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Git       1.9.1

      Bundler settings

  gem.test
    Set for the current user (/home/my_username/.bundle/config): "minitest"
  gem.mit
    Set for the current user (/home/my_username/.bundle/config): "false"
  gem.coc
    Set for the current user (/home/my_username/.bundle/config): "false"
  orig_path
    Set via BUNDLE_ORIG_PATH: "/home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin:/home/my_username/.rbenv/libexec:/home/my_username/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/my_username/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/my_username/.rbenv/shims:/home/my_username/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```